# Wizard using Orc.Controls.Wizard and Catel

Tags: wpf, wizard, catel

I'm trying to create a wizard using Catel 5.4.0.0 and Orc.Wizard 2.0.0.0

I followed the example on https://opensource.wildgums.com/orc.wizard/ but when I call the wizard it returns the error "The view model of the view 'QuotationWizardPageView' could not be resolved.

Here is some code

```
using Orc.Wizard
using System

namespace ZMAdmin.ASWizard
{
    public class QuotationWizardPage : WizardPageBase
    {
        public QuotationWizardPage()
        {
            Title = "Offerte";
            Description = "Offerte";
        }
    }
}

using Orc.Wizard;
using System;

namespace ZMAdmin.ASWizard
{
    public class QuotationWizardPageViewModel : WizardPageViewModelBase<QuotationWizardPage>
    {
        public QuotationWizardPageViewModel(QuotationWizardPage wizardPage)
            : base(wizardPage)
        {
        }
    }
}

using Catel.Ioc;
using Orc.Wizard;

namespace ZMAdmin.ASWizard : WizardBase
{
    public ASWizard(ITypeFactory typeFactory)
        : base (typeFactory)
    {
        Tittle = "Bedrijfsnaam";
        
        this.AddPage<QuotationWizardPage>();
    }
}

<catel.UserControl x:Class="ZMAdmin.Views.QuotationWizardPageView"
                    xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
                    >
                    
</catel.UserControl>
```

in the app.xaml.cs I've

```
var MyViewLocator  = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewLocator>();
MyViewLocator.Register(typeof(QuotationWizardPageViewModel), typeof(QuotationWizardPageView));
```

And last I call the wizard using:

```
private async void OnAddQuotation()
{
    await _wizardService.ShowWizardAsync<ASWizard.ASWizard>();
}
```

The wizard displays, but returns the error, not  displaying the quotationView.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you posted is correct (but I see another issue where a namespace is inheriting from a base class), it's probably caused of namespace conflicts.

The view is located in `ZMAdmin.Views`
The view model is located in `ZMAdmin.ASWizard`

My recommendation is to use:

- View models: `ZMAdmin.ASWizard.ViewModels`
- Views: `ZMAdmin.ASWizard.Views`

Comment: Changing the namespaces to the suggested form and fixing the issue of the namespace inheriting from a base class did the trick. Thanks for the quick response.